# How to perform torch.meshgrid over multiple tensors in parallel?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Let's say we have a tensor x of size [60,9] and a tensor y of size [60,9]
Is it possible to do an operation like `xx,yy = torch.meshgrid(x,y)` such that xx and yy is of size [60,9,9] and `xx[i,:,:], yy[i,:,:]` is basically `torch.meshgrid(x[i],y[i])`?

The built-in `torch.meshgrid` operation only accepts 1d tensors, is it possible to do the above operation without using for loops (which is inefficient as it does not take use of GPU's parallel operation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you will gain anything since the initialization of the tensors is not done on the GPU. So a proposed approach would indeed be to loop over `x` and `y` or using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) as an iterable:

```
grids = map(torch.meshgrid, zip(x,y))
```

Comment: A quick question. What particular operation in deep learning gain a lot when using GPUs?

Comment: Matrix multiplications are faster on GPU, hence their use for deep learning.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this in the case when a grid is being generated for `grid_sample`, which is being called for a batch of images.

In particular, you have 2 tensors `grid_x`, `grid_y` with shape (M, N), where M is the batch size and N is the number of points per grid dimension. The grid you need for `grid_sample` is of size (M, N, N, 2), and you could obtain it by looping over the first dimension, applying:

```
for i in range(M):
    gx, gy = torch.meshgrid(grid_x[i], grid_y[i], indexing='ij')
    grid[i, :, :, 0] = gx
    grid[i, :, :, 1] = gy
```

A much more efficient way to do this is:

```
grid = torch.stack([grid_x.unsqueeze(-1).expand(M, -1, grid_y.shape[1]),
                    grid_y.unsqueeze(1).expand(M, grid_x.shape[1], -1)],
                    dim=-1
)
```

It's not very easy to read, but it shows an alternative to `meshgrid`.